# How do you create a twitter link that auto-populates the users status with some text?

Tags: twitter, hyperlink, anchor

How do you create a link (`<a>`) that will send the user to Twitter and auto-populate the status field with some text? I've clicked links like this before, but not sure how it's created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point the link to http://twitter.com/home?status=some_text

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks!

Also, I figured out that underscores don't work to produce spaces, they will produce actual underscores in the status update. You can use "%20" between characters to produce spaces in the status update.

Comment: the url should be encoded. The '+' also will produce a space.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a note to anyone who finds this in 2014 onwards, Twitters API has moved on and you now have to use http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=

More info can be found on this blog article http://camgould.com/blog/posts/creating-a-link-that-posts-a-tweet